# Access Typescript Class properties after construction

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

Let's say I have a class model `Person`

```
export class Person {
    name:string;
    lastname:string;
}
```

And in a controller I set a variable to this type of class.

```
Object.keys(person)
```

Returns only the defined Properties. Is there a way to access all the class properties without having to define each one of them? Or do I have to make a constructor in the class in order to initialize the object?

Comment: You seemed to be confused about the difference between class properties and instance properties. You need to give example input and expected output.

Comment: you must create an instance then use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames();` to get the instance properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate instance members using:

```
const person = new Person();

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(person).forEach((val, idx, array) => {
    console.log(val);
});
```

But there is an extra gotcha in TypeScript... if a property is never set, it doesn't appear in the output, so your example class:

```
class Person {
    name:string;
    lastname:string;
}
```

Actually has no properties if you just create a new instance without setting then setting the values, i.e.:

```
var Person = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Person() {
    }
    return Person;
}());
```

If you want to see them, make them constructor parameters, or set a default value.

Constructor Parameters:

```
class Person {
    constructor(public name: string, public lastname: string) { }
}
```

Default Values:

```
class Person {
    name: string = '';
    lastname: string = '';
}
```

Comment: thanks it works. I'll stick to the default values idea.